# Reducing the Voltage of Car Battery

Tags: voltage, dc-dc-converter

I've been looking around for an easy way to convert car battery 12v to 5v. I have seen some people saying that a simple resistor is all that is needed.

What I've tried so far is the DC to DC regulator. It works, but it's pretty expensive for such a cheap project. And not to mention it is twice the size of the project.

Following the ohm's law, it should mean that a single resistor with appropriate wattage rating should be fine to convert the car battery into a 5v supply. But the project used a max of 350mA, will the resistor or the project burn?

EDIT: The project will run even with ~100mA supply, but at some points it could go way up to ~350mA. Haven't tested it thoroughly but atleast 500mA would be sufficient. And yes, since it's a Microcontroller, a stable 5VDC would be preferred. And about destroying the OBD2 ports... Really I never had any thoughts about it.

Comment: A resistor solution will require constant load. Go for a simple 7805 instead.

Comment: At 350mA, make that a 7805 and a suitable heatsink.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Will it withstand the 12v? This is going to be a 24/7 projects but is in an air-conditioned area. And no, for size reason I can not add a heatsink into it, since the available space already is stuffed. The reason why I prefer another options rather than a DC to DC regulator is because of its size.

Comment: In that case, get yourself a 12 V -> 5 V COTS converter module.

Comment: @winny Sorry but what is COTS?

Comment: Commercial Off The Shelf

Comment: If you've got a car battery, why are you worried about the size of a voltage regulator? Without a heatsink, at 7V*350mA, a 7805 is dead, a resistor is equally large, a buck converter is the smallest choice because it wastes least heat.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Because the project will run through the OBD2 Port which is connected directly to the car battery.

Comment: Ouch. If you somehow render the OBD port inoperative, who fixes your car?

Comment: Is it constantly consuming 350mA or is it necessary for a short pulse? Might be you can use a supercapacitor (or even a regular one) to get that current burst and then charge the cap with a much lower current?

Comment: You can get DC-DC regulators for $1-5! You are literally asking for a USB phone charger.

Comment: Do you want a stable 5V output during cranking etc. too? If so I would check out some of the automotive-oriented power supplies at http://www.mini-box.com/s.nl/sc.8/category.13/.f

Comment: @Bort - Indeed. I recently purchased an automative 3A USB power supply module with 4 x USB sockets for less than $5.  Check ebay/aliexpress/the other usual cheap parts outlets.  I also have a variable-output DC-DC converter module here whose size is about 4cm x 2cm, so there's no reason such a thing needs to be large.

Comment: When using low Linear regulators where Vout<< 1/2 Vin the regulator dissipates more power than the load thus 5*350mA is only 1.75W, the regulator meanwhile fries at 3.3W without a heatsink.  It is possible to do it this way, but no need with better solutions at hand.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but so far all I need is size, due to the project being plugged into the OBD2, can't design the case to be any bigger.. If anyone found a small automotive power supply module that would be great. Anyway, it mostly runs at less than 100mA but at some points it could go way up to ~350mA. And yes, stable 5VDC is prefered. I purchased an automotive charger for around 2USD but it is too big for the current case!

Comment: Which part of the circuit which you haven't shown needs more than 100 mA at 5 V? A microcontroller shouldn't need 350 mA on its own. Maybe some other components can work at 12 V.

Comment: The microcontroller is connected with a GPS and BT module. So when all of them lights up it takes up to 350mA. Up to. Most of the time less. There is no other components else than the Microcontroller itself and the GPS and BT module.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A single resistor is not appropriate.  The voltage a resistor drops is proportional to the current thru it.  Even then the resulting voltage will vary with the input voltage.

At 350 mA out, a resistor or linear regulator will dissipate a lot of heat.  When the car is running, figure the input voltage could be as high as 14 V (13.6 V is a common value).  That means the linear pass element will drop 9 V.  At 350 mA thru it, it will dissipate 3.2 watts.  That's going to require some space and expense one way or another.  That's too much, for example, for a TO-220 in free air.  The forced air cooling or extra dissipation surface will be big and expensive.

The best answer is a buck regulator.  These are much more efficient, and are therefore smaller and cheaper since they don't have to deal with getting rid of all that heat.  There are many commonly available chips from a number of manufacturers (Microchip, ST, TI, Linear, etc) that come with the controller and switch integrated.  You add the inductor, input/output caps, and a few extra external parts.  A properly designed buck solution will be smaller than anything that can safely dissipate 3 watts.

Consider that car power can have a few 10s of volts spikes on it occasionally.  You need to get a buck switcher with a sufficiently high maximum input voltage, or put some kind of clamp in front of it.

Comment: Agreed. So far I've got my hands on a 12v-24v Buck Regulator to 5v. With the car battery rated at 12v, with a spike of 10v it should be somewhere around 22v, nearing its max input. Would it withstand it? It's big, but I don't see any other options as you said the best answer is a buck regulator. It's a KIS 3R33S on a breakout board.

Comment: @Tenzo: Car voltage spikes can go higher than 24 V.  If you're going to use a converter rated for only 24 V in, then you have to put a clamp in front of it.

Comment: Do you have any reference as for the car voltage spikes? Like the peak voltage? And sorry, what clamp? If I were to use a converter rated for 37v would it suffice?

Comment: Are there any all-in-one products rather than just the chip? I've been looking to take my PC PSU's 12V and knock it down to 5V to allow for more SSDs, but I can't seem to find any reliable information how I'd go about doing this.

Answer (score 12):

Convenience stores and discount retailers sell these things for as little as $1, they are called USB Car Charger Adapters. They are made to plug into the cigarette lighter port and provide output to a USB jack, but you could adapt it for your purpose.

Comment: I did this for my sister's powered wheelchair. I pulled voltage directly off the battery, bought a female 12v socket (like this one https://www.amazon.com/Roadpro-Battery-Cigarette-Lighter-Adapter/dp/B00065L2D8/ref=sr_1_sc_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1474051058) and then used a 12v to 5v car charger (like this one https://www.amazon.com/Car-Charger-Dual-Adapter-Screen/dp/B01HPMPFDC/ref=sr_1_2?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1474051153) This can handle up to 30V and 3A. Now she has a nifty phone charger right on her wheelchair (with a couple of fuses for added safety). You can figure out how to pull the 5V.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I want to make it clear that I agree with Olin that a DC-DC converter is the way to go and that DC-DC converter should be a Buck regulator.

But in the interests on completeness assuming you want to go with a linear solution you will still need to dissipate 3.2W maximum but this does not all need to be in your TO-220 regulator.

If you put a 12 ohm 2W resistor between the battery and the regulator you can reduce the dissipation in the regulator but this will still require a heatsink but you can get away with a smaller one.

Calculations for this:

[image]

Comment: First I will try to increase the case size so that the bulk regulator would fit. But if it doesn't work then I'll have to try yours. And yes I've always agreed and would use a buck regulator, but for the size, it just doesn't fit.

Answer (score 1):

try a switching regulator with a small footprint. something like MURATA's [OKI-78SR-5/1.5-W36H-C](http://power.murata.com/en/oki-78sr-5-1-5-w36-c.html)

It costs only 4$ and has a very wide input (7V to 37V) which may allow it work when cranking or when a load dump happens

[image]

Comment: I'll try to find that board here. It's pretty hard to find stuff like this >.>